# Using domain user in PSCP command?

Tags: putty, pscp

I use this command to copy file from Window to Linux with user "fred", it is successful

```
pscp  c:\temp\example-hosts.txt fred@10.53.x.x:/etc/hosts
```

But if my user name is domain user, such as: domain\fred. I got the error: More than remote source not supported

```
pscp c:\temp\example-hosts.txt domain\fred@10.53.x.x:/etc/hosts
```

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Thanks @MartinPrikryl

Answer (score 0):

Add the `-l` flag for user

```
pscp -l domain\fred c:\temp\example-hosts.txt 10.53.x.x:/etc/hosts
```